Speed up the data save to S3 buckets using spark scala
I am looking out for some pointers by which I can fasten the speed at which data is being persisted to S3. So I am currently persisting data to s3 buckets based on the below example path
s3://pipeline_processed_events/name=<determined_name>/subject=<subject_name>/year=2024/month=06/day=10/

<determined_name> is evaluated on run time and the whole dataframe is being then filtered based on the name field and persisted to s3 bucket code for it shows below
   val finalEventList = sc.broadcast(dataFrame.select("name").distinct()
    .map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList).value

  finalEventList.par.foreach {
    determined_name =>
      val targetPath = bucketname + "/name=" + determined_name + datePath
      modifiedFinalDf.filter(col("name") === determined_name).write
        .mode(
          fileWriteMode match {
            case FILE_WRITE.APPEND => SaveMode.Append
            case FILE_WRITE.OVER_WRITE => SaveMode.Overwrite
            case FILE_WRITE.DEFAULT => SaveMode.Ignore
          }
        ).parquet(targetPath)
  }

Though the data is getting persisted but the time it takes for saving the data is too high, even if the finalEventList is having size less than 10. Is there any way by which I can fasten the process.
Any pointer are welcome.
Thanks

This issue can potentially be related to the type of committer you are using you can try using the magic commmiter from S3 you can add this configuration to enable it
“spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.all.committer.magic.enabled”: “true”

that only sets it for the bucket "all". if you've been hoping that works and you have a bucket with any other name -it hasn't. read the s3a docs on "per-bucket settings"

magic committer is already enabled that doesn't help much.
@stevel will take a look at documentation

look for a non-empty _SUCCESS file to see what committer was used and what the statistics of the job were.
